redis lua script can't call on global
local function get_cur_time()
    local current_time = redis.call('TIME')[1] 
    local current_minute_start = math.floor(current_time / 60) * 60
    return current_minute_start
end

-- add below line would failed
-- local CURRENT_TIME = get_cur_time()

redis.register_function('get_cur_time', get_cur_time)

I'd like reuse CURRENT_TIME in many place in my script, but once I added it to global scope, raise error:

redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Error registering functions: ERR user_function:6: Script attempted to access nonexistent global variable 'call'

Anyway to get around?
